# SAPUI5 UI Table ScrollBar Width And Hight Issue

Tags: css, sapui5

I'm developing an UI5 application and since the application is used on high resolution televisions I need to change ui.Table's scrollbar width and hight size. I've tried a couple of methods be able to do that. But I couldn't change scrollbar size anyway. How can I change that scrollbar's width and hight ?

[image]

Here is the code blocks that I tried to change scrollbar width;

```
.sapUiTable ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 36px !important;
   height: 36px !important;
}

.sapUiTable ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background-color: #005483 !important;
}

.sapUiTable ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
   background-color: #d14900 !important;
}

html.sap-desktop ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 36px !important;
   height: 36px !important;
}
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: "high resolution televisions I need to change ui.Table's scrollbar" why just the scrollbars, everything else stays small? Webpages use usually a viewport to scale content.

Comment: I've used "rem" measurement unit for all components. When I change the html tag's fontsize property every component is scaled up. But scrollbar's width and height stay same size. It doesn't effect

Comment: try the scale option in the Viewport or set a smaller Viewport. You can't just increase some css sizes an expect that everything works